# Symfony 2 autocomplete routing

Tags: forms, symfony, autocomplete

I install this bundle:[GenemuFormBudnle](https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle) and  I try to made an ajax autocomplete. I have this in my Form:

```
$builder
            ->add('PermitsCompany', 'genemu_jqueryautocompleter_entity', array(
                'route_name' => 'ajax_company',
                'class' => 'MainCoreBundle:Company',
            ));
```

This in my controller: **NewController.php**

```
/**
     * @Route("/ajax_company", name="ajax_company")
     */
    public function ajaxCompanyAction(Request $request)
    {
        $value = $request->get('id');

        $permits = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('JokerCoreBundle:Company')->findAjaxValue($value);


        $json = array();
        foreach ($permits as $permit) {
            $json[] = array(
                'label' => $permit->getName(),
                'value' => $permit->getId()
            );
        }

        $response = new Response();
        $response->setContent(json_encode($json));

        return $response;
    }
```

And this in my route:

```
ajax_company:
  defaults: { _controller: MainCoreBundle:Permits:ajaxCompany}
  pattern:  /ajax_company/
  type:     annotation
```

Here is an error message:

> AnnotationException: [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Route" in
>   method Main\CoreBundle\Controller\NewController::ajaxCompanyAction()
>   was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for
>   this annotation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following line to the top of your Controller:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
```

Without it, the Controller doesn't have the ability to load the Class properly from the annotations.

A proper JSON Response should also have the `Content-Type` set correctly:

```
$response = new Response(json_encode($json));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return $response;
```

According to [these docs](https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle/blob/af36b33d798c3ddca2ea475d09beee3385626a73/Resources/doc/jquery/autocomplete/entity_ajax.md), your builder is slightly incorrect. Use this instead:

```
$builder
    ->add('PermitsCompany', 'genemu_jqueryautocompleter_entity', array(
        'route_name' => 'ajax_company',
        'class' => 'MainCoreBundle\Entity\Company', // Must use namespace here with slashes
    ))
;
```

I've examined the `GenemuFormBundle` repository and it looks like a `findAjaxValue` function isn't provided or injected with the bundle into your entity repositories. You must either create the `findAjaxValue` function in your repository or revert to a helper function, such as `findBy` like such:

```
$permits = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('JokerCoreBundle:Company')->findBy(array(
    'name' => $value,
));
```

The bundle you're trying to use doesn't look like a complete solution, nor does it intend to be one:

> There are maybe some bugs in those implementations, this package is just an idea of form types which can be very useful for your Symfony2 projects.

maybe you should bear that in mind and try to come up with your own solution instead, or find an alternate bundle.

Comment: Now error disappered THANKS:) but have you got any idea why autocomplete still didnt work? I got an empty text input but when I type something it dont autocomplete it...

Comment: Is this a Route problem?

Comment: @Cre3k You should examine the console and network tab in your Developer Tools or Firebug depending on which browser you're using. Did you try loading the `/ajax_company` route directly in your browser?

Comment: Undefined method 'findAjaxValue'.

Comment: @Cre3k So you should start there... I can't help you without your front-end code

Comment: Just remark:
$response = new Response();
$response->setContent(json_encode($json));
Change to: $response = new JsonResponse($json);

Comment: But still this: Undefined method 'findAjaxValue'